# How can I exclude content in my notifications bar from being indexed?

Tags: seo, google, website-design, google-website-optimizer

Of course I want my content to be indexed pretty fast by search engines, however not my notifications bar.

My notifications bar contains the last 30 changes to content on the site, and I don't want this to show in my SEO meta. As all the notifications are generic, it often doesn't provide any relevant information.

As I said the notifications are generic. If an article named "123" was created, it would create a notification that says "Article "123" was created by xxx at 12:00AM". I'm now wondering if this is a content design problem. As only 1/3 of this information is actually relevant to users (the title, what happened).

By SEO meta, and irrelevant notification data being shown, I mean this -

[image]

Basically what I was wondering, is how I could optimise this, so search engines wouldn't show this generic nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that screenshot is for the domain you're talking about, the first thing you should be doing is actually providing a meta description in the first place. Right now it's blank. It's not guaranteed the engines will use your meta description, but the reason they're digging into your page content in the first place is that you're not even making a suggestion.

Back to preventing these notifications from being indexed, you could try using a bit of Javascript to load the notification content with Ajax. A quick and dirty way would be writing the notifications to a small HTML snippet file and then pulling it with something like jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

Comment: Ooo, I didn't even notice the no meta description, but I guess thats why its called Beta. Thanks for pointing it out though. Also I'll try loading the notifications, good idea!